# Unknown System Variable "no_more_data" at Mysql Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1193

I'm new using mysql stored procedure. There is error that I can't fix
this is my code

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `bankdb`.`charge` () 
BEGIN
DECLARE idcust_val INT;
DECLARE balance_val FLOAT;
DECLARE productCd_val VARCHAR(10);

DECLARE loop_cntr INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE col_cur CURSOR FOR
select c.cust_id, c.balance, c.product_cd
from account c;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET no_more_rows = TRUE;

OPEN col_cur;
select FOUND_ROWS() into num_rows;

read_loop: LOOP
FETCH col_cur INTO idcust_val, balance_val, productCd_val;

IF no_more_rows THEN
close col_cur;
leave read_loop;
END IF;

IF productCd_val == 'SAV' || productCd_val == 'CD' THEN
    IF balance_val == 2000 THEN
          balance_val = balance_val-10;
          UPDATE account SET avail_balance = balance_val
          WHERE account_id =idcust_val;
    END IF;
END IF;

IF productCd_val == 'CHK' || productCd_val == 'SAV' || productCd_val == 'MM'
|| productCd_val == 'CD' THEN
  balance_val = balance_val + (balance_val*0,05);
  UPDATE account SET avail_balance = balance_val
  WHERE account_id =idcust_val;
ELSE
  balance_val = balance_val - (balance_val*0,1);
  UPDATE account SET avail_balance = balance_val
  WHERE account_id =idcust_val;
END IF;
 SET loop_cntr = loop_cntr + 1;
END LOOP;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

when I execute it, mysql query browser show error like this:

> Script line: 3    Unknown system variable 'no_more_rows'

please help me!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A variable no_more_rows must be delared, write next line at the begining of the procedure's body.

   DECLARE no_more_rows INT DEFAULT 0;
2. Equal operator is '='

   IF productCd_val == 'SAV' and etc. should be IF productCd_val = 'SAV'
3. Use SET command to assigns values, e.g. -

   SET balance_val = balance_val - 10;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830389/error-operand-should-contain-1-columns-stored-procedure/5830540#5830540